# Ubuntu 16.04 | Upstart killing my process right after it starts

Tags: ubuntu, server, startup, ubuntu-16.04, upstart

I'm trying to run the binary monerod right on startup and it runs but gets killed right after.

Upstart .conf code:

```
start on started [redis]
stop on shutdown
script
        exec /home/crypto/daemon/monerod
end script

pre-stop script
        echo /var/log/upstart/monerod.log >> /home/crypto/monero.log
end script
```

monerod.log from /var/log/upstart :

```
^[[0m^[[1;37m2016-Oct-04 18:38:52.388997 Loading precomputed blocks: 1138751
^[[0m^[[1;32m2016-Oct-04 18:38:52.443751 Blockchain initialized. last block: 0,$
^[[0m^[[1;37m2016-Oct-04 18:38:52.659898 Core initialized OK
^[[0m^[[1;37m2016-Oct-04 18:38:52.660009 Starting core rpc server...
^[[0m^[[1;37m2016-Oct-04 18:38:52.660192 Run net_service loop( 2 threads)...
^[[0m^[[1;37m2016-Oct-04 18:38:52.660551 [SRV_MAIN]Core rpc server started ok
^[[0m^[[1;37m2016-Oct-04 18:38:52.660875 [SRV_MAIN]Starting p2p net loop...
^[[0m^[[1;37m2016-Oct-04 18:38:52.661142 [SRV_MAIN]Run net_service loop( 10 thr$
^[[0m^[[1;37m2016-Oct-04 18:38:52.661169 [node] Stop signal sent
^[[0m^[[1;37m2016-Oct-04 18:38:52.661197 [SRV_MAIN]net_service loop stopped.
^[[0m^[[1;37m2016-Oct-04 18:38:52.661465 [SRV_MAIN]p2p net loop stopped
^[[0m^[[1;37m2016-Oct-04 18:38:52.661512 [SRV_MAIN]Stopping core rpc server...
^[[0m^[[1;37m2016-Oct-04 18:38:52.661690 [SRV_MAIN]Node stopped.
^[[0m^[[1;37m2016-Oct-04 18:38:52.661735 [SRV_MAIN]Deinitializing rpc server...
^[[0m^[[1;37m2016-Oct-04 18:38:52.661969 [SRV_MAIN]Deinitializing p2p...
^[[0m^[[1;37m2016-Oct-04 18:38:52.662407 [SRV_MAIN]Deinitializing core...
^[[0m^[[1;37m2016-Oct-04 18:38:52.662600 [SRV_MAIN]Closing IO Service.
^[[0m^[[1;37m2016-Oct-04 18:38:52.663436 [SRV_MAIN]Deinitializing cryptonote_pr$
^[[0mCreating the logger system
```

As you can see somehow the script gets terminated @ "[node]: stop signal sent".
The script runs fine when I run it manually and also when I run it from a shell that executes the program, it's only when I use it as a service that it doesn't work.

I've also diagnosed the CPu and RAM usage during the short while that the service actually runs using DSAT and it's ~1% on both, so there's no shortage of hardware.

Server specs: 2GB ram & 2CPU cores (DigitalOcean)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know the binary that you are trying to run, but a common reason in these cases is that it is running as a different user each time. Are you sure you are trying to run it with the same user ?

Comment: It's running on startup so I assume it's running under the root user.

Comment: Since you run it as root and complete successfully, i would check if this binary needs other services running (another common startup failure) and config it (`http://askubuntu.com/questions/21378/how-can-i-make-sure-one-upstart-job-starts-before-other-upstart-jobs` ) to start after them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running `monerod` in interactive mode, which will terminate when standard input is `/dev/null`. You can fix this by adding `--non-interactive`. (You may also want to examine the `--detach` option.)

Answer (score 0):

The link from ubuntu wiki   [compares Upstart and systemd](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers) and  workaround to fix issues related to Upstart and systemd, systemd was introduced as from Ubuntu 15.04 and later versions